# jQuery trying to center tooltip over hovered element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing my own tooltip function like so:

```
$(".tip_holder").hover(
  function() {

      var $containerWidth = $(this).width();

      var $containerHeight = $(this).height();

      var $tipTxt = $(this).text();

      var $tipTitle = $(this).attr('title');

      var $offset = $(this).offset();

      $('#icis_dashboard').prepend('<div id="tooltip">' + $tipTxt + '</div>');

      $('#tooltip').css({
          'position': 'absolute'
      });

      var $tipWidth = $('#tooltip').width();

      var $tipHeight = $('#tooltip').height();

      $('#tooltip').css({
          'top': $offset.top - ($tipHeight + 5),
          'left': $offset.left,
          'padding': '0 5px 5px'              
      });

  },
  function() {
      $('#tooltip').remove();
  }
);
```

However i am having difficulty centering the tooltip over the element that i am hovering over.  I need this to scale to any size element that is hovered.

I appreciate that there are many plugins to achieve this functionality but i wanted to write my own so that the tooltip div would only ever appear in the same place in the code so that it is testable by my tester.  This is a requirement from him to make his life easier :(

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jquery & jquery-ui?

Comment: Yes.  I didn't think tooltip was supported in jQuery UI yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of jQuery and the jQuery-ui then you can use the position tool to center the tool tip above the element.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

Edit in response to authors answer.

```
$(".tip_holder").hover(function(){
    var currentTipHolder = $(this);
    var $tipTxt = $(this).text();
    var $tipTitle = $(this).attr('title');

    $('#icis_dashboard').prepend('<div id="tooltip">' + $tipTxt + '</div>');

    // jQueryUI position
    $('#tooltip').position({
        of: currentTipHolder,
        at: 'center top',
        my: 'center bottom'
    });
},function() {
    $('#tooltip').remove();
});
```

Comment: Is that bundled in the core or do i need to download extras?

Comment: It is an extra in the ui core section of the download page. http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: Holy crap you & jQuery rock. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Using Jquery UI JUST FOR A TOOLTIP is a HORRIBLE HORRIBLE HORRIBLE idea, HORRIBLE. Jquery UI adds a TON of weight to your page for something that can be achieved in 1/100th of a kb... geez

Comment: true, though it is possible to just download the position util separate to the entire UI

Comment: @android.nick -- if you call jqueryui from the Google CDN, not only will the HTTP request be made in parallel, but the odds are good that your visitors will already have it in cache, so the cost to your page weight is virtually 0 -- cheaper than writing your own implementation, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML** :

```
<div id="icis_dashboard" ></div>
blah blah<br/>
blah blah<br/>

<center>
     <div class="tip_holder" >ToolTip !!</div>
</center>

blah blah<br/>
blah blah<br/>
```

**CSS**

```
.tip_holder {
    color : #0099f9;
    font : bold 20px Arial;
    width : 100px;
    background:#000;
    border:1px #f0f;
}
#tooltip{
    color:#f0f;
    background:#2f2f2f;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    font : bold 15px verdana;
}
```

finally some **JavaScript** :

```
$(".tip_holder").hover(function() {

      var $containerWidth = $(this).width();
      var $offset = $(this).offset();

      $('#icis_dashboard')
          .prepend('<div id="tooltip">' + $(this).text()  + '</div>');

      var $tipWidth = $('#tooltip').width();

      var $tipHeight = $('#tooltip').height();

      $('#tooltip').css({
          'top': $offset.top - ( $tipHeight + 15 ),
          'left': $offset.left - ( $tipWidth - $containerWidth  ) /2 ,
          'position':'absolute',
          'display':'block'
      });

      },function() {
         $('#tooltip').remove();
});
```

**Demo** : **http://jsfiddle.net/Nb3uW/**